# jQuery hide(), show() or html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a

```
<div id="content">
</div>
```

and three js variables that store different html: `content1`, `content2` and `content3`.

By user interactions, the content of mentioned above div changes to one of that that stored in js variables.

What is preferable either to directly set `div` content to what I need by user interaction:

```
$("#content").html(content2);
```

or to change `div` structure to:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="c1">
        // value of content1 variable here
    </div>
    <div id="c2">
        // value of content2 variable here
    </div>
    <div id="c3">
        // value of content3 variable here
    </div>
</div>
```

And doing `hide()` and `show()` to that inner blocks, i.e when I want content2 to be shown:

```
$("#c1").hide();
$("#c2").show();
$("#c3").hide();
```

?

Comment: Each of this content variables consists of many lines of html with images, I thought that it's maybe better for performance to keep all of them in DOM and just hiding, showing them than remove and create them again on each user interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two aren't really all-that comparable since they do different things. They may well give a similar perception but what's happening isn't the same in terms of markup. In fact, it's not uncommon to see `.html('Something').show()` chained together.

- Passing a string to `.html()` replaces the **content** of the selected element, it does nothing to affect the element itself.
- Calling `.show()` or `.hide()` *only* affects the element itself - all the descendants remain exactly the same, they just can't be seen because their parent is not being displayed.

By using `.html()` you are replacing everything inside your element. All references to these descending elements will become undefined and direct (non-delegated) event listeners will also be lost.

`.hide()` and `.show()` do exactly what they say. The data inside your element is still preserved, the event handlers still in place, it's all just 'hidden' by way of `display: none`.

If the content dynamically changes, without page-load, use `.html()`, if not, `.show()` and `.hide()` are more appropriate.

Comment: What do you mean by "If the content is always changing"? My variables consist of many html lines with images. So that is why I thought that maybe my second solution will save time for loading the again and from repeatedly creating and removing big html chunks on every user interactionl

Comment: @Tigrokonvel I mean dynamically changing, without a page reload/redirection.

Comment: So what would be your advice if, as I said, my variables consist of many html lines with images but I load content to that variables once and keep it in js variables?

Comment: I would say definitely use `.show()` and `.hide()` there is no reason for you to keep replacing the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say hiding & showing divs.

It's less intensive, and if the content inside the javascript variables happens to contain elements that you'll bind to, you won't have to rebind everytime you refresh the content, and if you wanted to have some sort of animation between the different content, multiple divs also allows that.

As a side note, using jQuery it's less code to do something like

```
$("#c2").show().siblings().hide();
```

Comment: Didn't know about siblings() method. Thanks)

Answer (score 0):

For the ease of use and shorter more cleaner looking code, setting the content through HTML is the right option!

Think of it as what you're trying to do, 1 DIV => Can contain 3 different contents, you can manipulate it through JS.

So, in your first solution, you actually have one div and manipulating it through JS:

```
$("#content").html(content1);
$("#content").html(content2);
$("#content").html(content3);
```

Whereas, in the second solution, you are actually using 4 divs for the same functionality! So definitely, if you can do something with 1 div. That's the preferred way.

They both are taking equal lines for JS, but with the second approach, your HTML will contain a lot more code considering your contents are large.

Comment: Of course, first solution looked better for me. But as each of this content variables consists of many html, I thought that it's maybe better for performance to keep all of them in DOM and just hiding, showing them than remove and create them again on each user interaction.

Comment: Yes, if the content is a lot of HTML rather than some text you're adding removing then ofcourse add that HTML in your HTML beforehand for obvious performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best solution is to store the different contents into three variables and then assign to the div the choosen one with

```
$("#content").html(content2);
```

In this way you have three less nodes on your DOM tree

Answer (score 0):

There isn't that much difference between the two options. One factor that might affect this is the actual size of the content you are changing. If the content is relatively small then it really doesn't matter which way you choose.

Another thing to consider is how available the three versions of the content variable is. If you have to fetch this HTML content each time you load it then it might make sense to pre-populate the content before you display it to your users so as to save the time it takes to load it. Then just show/hide the appropriate content.

Comment: What do you mean by "pre-populate"? My variables consist of many html lines with images. So that is why I thought that maybe my second solution will save time for loading the again and from repeatedly creating and removing big html chunks on every user interactionl

Comment: @Tigrokonvel - By pre-populate I mean having the 3 `<div>` elements on your page and populating all of them with the content before the user has made any action. Then showing/hiding them according to their actions.

Comment: So what would be your advice if, as I said, my variables consist of many html lines with images but I load content to that variables once and keep it in js variables?

Comment: @Tigrokonvel - And the data is available to you as soon as the page loads? They are not being retrieved later via AJAX or something else?

Comment: yes, They are loaded once. But consist of many lines and images

Comment: If you already have them in hand then you should place the content into the `<div>` elements as soon as you can (on page load) so that when the user does decide to view that content, it's already ready and waiting for them.